# Change IntelliJ border colors

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a  [Github](https://github.com/cyberquarks/enki-aster-theme-intellij) repo for a simple IntelliJ theme:

[image]

Which color would be based on https://github.com/enkia/enki-theme (pretty much)

How do I change the color of the borders (those with red circles on them?)

Here's my theme `Enki-Theme.theme.json` code:

```json
{
  "name": "Enki Theme",
  "dark": true,
  "author": "Cyberquarks",
  "editorScheme": "/Enki_Theme.xml",
  "ui": {
    "*": {
      "background": "#16161B",
      "foreground": "#5B5D6D",
      "selectionBackground": "#20222C",
      "selectionForeground": "#5B5D6D",
      "borderColor":"#1E1E25",
      "disabledBorderColor": "#1E1E25",
      "focusColor": "#1E1E25",
      "focusedBorderColor": "#1E1E25",
      "hoverBorderColor": "#1E1E25",
      "pressedBorderColor": "#1E1E25",
      "separatorColor": "#1E1E25",
      "lineSeparatorColor": "#1E1E25"
    },
    "EditorTabs": {
      "selectedForeground": "#ACB0D0",
      "selectedBackground": "#ACB0D0",
      "inactiveMaskColor": "#16161B",

      "underlineColor": "#ACB0D0",
      "underlineHeight": 2,

      "underlinedTabBackground": "#16161B",
      "inactiveColoredFileBackground": "#00000000",
      "borderColor":"#1E1E25"
    },
    "Panel": {
      "background": "#19191F",
      "foreground": "#5B5D6D",
      "borderColor":"#1E1E25",
      "focusedBorderColor": "#1E1E25",
      "hoverBorderColor": "#1E1E25",
      "pressedBorderColor": "#1E1E25"
    },
    "StatusBar.borderColor": "#1E1E25",
    "ToolWindow": {
      "Header": {
        "background": "#16161B",
        "inactiveBackground": "#16161B",
        "borderColor":"#1E1E25"
      }
    },
    "Window.border": "4,4,4,4,1E1E25",
    "Component": {
      "focusWidth": "1",
      "focusColor": "#484A58",
      "focusedBorderColor": "#484A58",
      "borderColor": "#1E1E25"
    },

    "Button": {
      "default": {
        "startBackground": "#404F76",
        "endBackground": "#404F76",
        "focusedBorderColor": "#484A58",
        "focusColor": "#1E1E25",
        "foreground": "#1E1E25"
      },
      "startBackground": "#1E1E25",
      "endBackground": "#1E1E25",
      "focusedBorderColor": "#1E1E25",
      "disabledBorderColor": "#1E1E25",
      "borderColor": "#1E1E25"
    }
  }
}
```

Which setting should I set or add on the JSON theme to change the border colors? *I've looked everywhere but I can't find a manual on what are the possible JSON configuration for themes.*

Comment: Try adding border node to UI. See https://github.com/thvardhan/Gradianto/blob/master/src/main/resources/Gradianto_Nature_Green.theme.json#L57